# Can I transfer my PHPmailer folders from a windows PC to hosting site

Tags: phpmailer, cpanel

I finally have PHPmailer, using gmail.php working on my test environment, using windows 11.
Can I just transfer the folders from windows 11 to my godaddy account or do I need to install PHPmailer?

Transfer folders from windows 11 to godaddy, using cpanel.

Comment: It's unlikely to work easily as GoDaddy blocks outbound SMTP, as the PHPMailer docs cover in detail. Apart from that, there's no particular reason it will work differently to your Windows setup, so long as you have an appropriate version of PHP (which should be 8.1 or later).